# Choosing 6 different cells from a 50 cell array by using rand(start,end) only 6 times

Tags: c, random

I was trying to think of an algorithm which chooses 6 random cells from an array with 50 cells, such that the probability for each cell to be picked is equal.
I need to find a solution that uses the function Random(start,end) no more than 6 times.

I can't use any extra data structure, and it is important that the probability for each cell to be picked will be equal and independent.

Comment: I dont think that you can guarantee only '6 times' solution. If you will exclude each chosen value - then probability will be different, if you not exclude values - you can end up with the repeated values..

Comment: I have managed to do it with a linked list of values, and when i pick a value, i remove the cell from the list and picking a random number between 0 and 48 and so on... the problem is that i use an extra DS.

Comment: it doesnt meet your criteria, as you stated that probability has to be equal

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov - if i exclude a value, the probability for the **current** stage would be different, but the probability beforehand can stay equal (i.e. before i run the algorithm, the probability for each number to show up is equal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call Random(0,49). Read the resulting cell, then shuffle everything after it in the array down one place so that you have a 49-cell array with the picked value missing.

Call Random(0,48) and repeat 6 times.

Comment: probability will be different

Comment: the probabilities will be 1/50, 1/49, 1/48 .. each time you remove a cell.

Comment: Just mathematics, nothing personal :) P1(1/50), P2(1/49), P3(1/48).. but OP needs constant Pn(1/50)

Comment: The definition of the problem states that he must pick 6 cells.  He could use random(0,50) for each selection and then discard the result if it's a duplicate, but the result is the same as using the suggested solution.  By selecting one, you are automatically reducing the pool of possibilities.  You state it as 1/50, 1/49, which is technically true, but it's really 1/50, 1/49 + 1/1, 1/48 + 1/1 + 1/1..

Maybe it's a trick question where we are supposed to allow picking the same cell twice .. ?

Comment: Hm.. yes, you're right. If we'd need to get 6 random values from 6 elements long array - we'd end up with 1/6 1/5 1/4 1/3 1/2 1/1.. so yes.

Comment: I need to get 6 indexes of cells. That solution is correct but it will mess my array (i might need the rest of the cells in the future) so i have to create another array and run your algorithm over it. That means using another data structure (and i want to avoid that)

Comment: @Eyal, these are very bizarre constraints when taken together (no extra data structures, no more than 6 calls to rand(), might need the cells later so can't delete....) are you SURE this isn't homework?

Comment: No, that's a question from a job interview... I accepted this solution because it is very simple and using an extra array (simple DS)

Comment: You don't have to move the data in the array after you extract an element. You just have to adjust the indexes. After you get your first random number you "remove" that element from the array ( let's say # x ). When you generate the second one (between 0 and 48) all numbers >= x actually point to x+1 in the initial array. You just need some space to keep track of the previously selected indexes.

Comment: @tomato +1. Allow me to clarify that: every "picked" element is swapped with the element in the i-th place (i is the iteration number), and the next iteration calls `Random(i, 50)`. In each iteration the original indices of the "picked" elements are also stored in memory so that they can be swapped back to restore the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Put the cells in a list, shuffle it, take six of 'em

Comment: putting the cells in a list means that i use another data structure

Comment: and another thing - shuffling must use random... but you can use it only 6 times.

Comment: My answer would still be above, I'd argue that the constraints were artificial, stupid and that any dev who accepted them was incompetent. They can disagree of course but I wouldn't care because I wouldn't work for anyone dumb enough to believe this was a realistic scenario anyway.